# Novel written in the 1960s or 1970s about pyramid exploration on Mars

Tags: story-identification, novel

A team of astronauts on Mars discover an inverted pyramid buried on Mars. They explore it. Towards the end I found someone had torn out the final pages. The copy I read was a plain yellow cover published by Gollancz?  It has bugged me ever since I got it from a library when I was a boy. It wasn't a kids book.